# cocos2d-x PageView Keep turning final page to first page...Help me

Tags: cocos2d-x, pageviews

ex)5 is last page, I set setBounceEnabled(true) because I want to bounce action.
But keep turning last to first page and I don't understand why.
I checked cocos's test projects, they not moving when it was last page.
I set like this:

```
pageView->addEventListenerPageView(this, pagevieweventselector(CSceneShop::pageViewEvent));
pageView->setBounceEnabled(true);
pageView->setIndicatorEnabled(false);
pageView->setDirection(PageView::Direction::HORIZONTAL);
pageView->setBackGroundImageScale9Enabled(true);
```

If set pageView->setBounceEnabled(false); then no turning(last->first) & no bounece, but I need bounce.
Plz help me...................................

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
pageView->setClippingEnabled(true);
```

It will be fine